# Transform lbm.in/min² into Newton

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, units, dimensional-analysis

The units of physical quantities are important for the transformation of units, achieving coherence. So I need to transfom `10000 lbm.in/min²` into `N (Newton)`. But that's is not a trivial transformation, how do I could start this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know the [definition of the `Newton`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_(unit))
in terms of `kg`, `m` and `s`$.

Loook up the conversions between `1 lbm` and `1 kg`, `1 in` and `1 m`, `1 min` and `1 s`.

Now you should be able to do the math and get the final result.

Comment: Hi, you've answered a problem (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/152902/rotating-observers-in-special-relativity-coriolis-like-effect/536057#536057 ) very similar to one I'm asking about here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061155/im-trying-to-calculate-the-covariant-derivatives-of-this-rotating-system-to-dis if you could help me that would be great. if you could just tell me if what i'm doing is impossible or not.