# Will rotating observer see space curved?

Tags: special-relativity, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, curvature, centrifugal-force

According to Einstein's field equation, there should be zero curvature. But if one measures the circumference over radius for a circle perpendicular to the rotating axis and centered at the observer, the ratio would not be 2pi

Comment: No according to Einstein equations, there should *not* be zero curvature. Even in vacuum, the [Weyl tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor) can be non-zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating Observers in Special Relativity: Coriolis-like effect?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/152902/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Euclidean geometry in non-inertial frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201492/)